# Релиз в Jenkins из конкретной ветки

Tags: jenkins

Проблема следующая: у нас на проекте микросервисная архитектура, т.е. репозиториев много (порядка 40). Хочется для каждого проекта иметь сборку и для feature-бранчей и для релизных. Но для релиза нужно выполнить некоторые дополнительные действия (например сначала инкрементить версию, а потом собрать) и сделать это нужно именно в релизной ветке (например *master*). На данный момент я знаю как это сделать только путём создания 2х тасок, например `myrepo_release` и `myrepo_all_branches`, но, как я писал выше, репозиториев много и если на каждый делать по 2 задачи, то разобраться в этом будет очень не просто.

Есть ли способ в *Jekins* сделать это в одной таске? Например как вот [здесь](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multi-Branch+Project+Plugin) только с возможностью на каждую ветку сделать отдельную задачу.

P.S. что уже посмотрел: 
Batch Task - всё здорово, но нет возможности запускать по триггеру (как то пуш в репозиторий)